# Using jlayer/javazoom, or vlcj to playback audio (MPEG4, RAW AMR, or THREE GPP)

Tags: mpeg, 3gp, amr, vlcj, jlayer

Can jlayer/javazoom, or vlcj playback MPEG4, RAW AMR, or THREE GPP?

I have searched, and I cannot find how to correctly use the players, or whether they even support playback of these file formats. Are there any other players that can playback these audio formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Xuggler http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/ for playing AMR from files. It uses ffmpeg with opencore-amr-nb. And I think it can play other formats. You can start from http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndPlayAudio.java

Comment: This seems like it would work, thanks. Although I've decided that flash is much more user friendly then executable jars for what I'm developing. But still, the help is appreciated.